# FastAPI JWT Invalid Token

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jwt, fastapi

Trying to figure out why I'm getting an invalid token error given my code below. I'm testing registration and authentication via my API.

I create a dummy account and then check my email for the verification link. Everything is working great until I click on the link in the email and receive a 400 bad request and due to my debugging the error is caused by an "Invalid Token".

here is my code:

**route_user.py:**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, status
from fastapi import Depends
from jose import jwt

from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate, ShowUser
from db.repository.users_data_access_layer import Users
from core.auth import Auth
from core.mailer import Mailer
from core.config import Settings
from depends import get_user_db

router = APIRouter()

get_settings = Settings()


@router.post("/", response_model=ShowUser)
async def create_user(form_data: UserCreate = Depends(), users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    if await users.check_user(email=form_data.email) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="User already exists"
        )
    elif await users.check_username(username=form_data.username) is not None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Username already exists"
        )

    new_user = await users.register_user(username=form_data.username, email=form_data.email, hashed_password=form_data.password)
    #print(new_user)
    confirmation = Auth.get_confirmation_token(new_user.id)
    #print(confirmation)
    new_user.confirmation = confirmation["jti"]
    # users.db_session.add(new_user)
    # await users.db_session.flush()
    print(new_user.confirmation)
    


    try:
        Mailer.send_confirmation_message(confirmation["token"], form_data.email)
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            detail="Email couldn't be send. Please try again."
        )
    # users.db_session.add(new_user)
    # await users.db_session.flush()
    #return new_user

@router.get("/verify/{token}")
async def verify(token: str, users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    invalid_token_error = HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid Token")
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, get_settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[get_settings.TOKEN_ALGORITHM])
        print(payload['sub'])
        print(payload['jti'])
    except jwt.JWSError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Token has Expired")
    if payload['scope'] != 'registration':
        raise invalid_token_error
    #print(payload['sub'])
    user = await users.get_user_by_id(id=payload['sub'])
    #print(user)
    #print('hello2')
    #print(user)
    print(User.confirmation)
    print(User.id)
    if not user or await users.get_confirmation_uuid(str(User.confirmation)) != payload['jti']:
        print('hello')
        raise invalid_token_error
    # if user.is_active:
    #     #print('hello2')
    #     raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="User already Activated")
    # user.confirmation = None
    # user.is_active = True
    # return user
```

**user_data_access_layer:**

```
from core.hashing import Hasher
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists


from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate
from core.hashing import Hasher


db_session = Session

class Users():
    
    def __init__(self, db_session: Session):
        self.db_session = db_session

    
            #print('user created')

    async def register_user(self, username: str, email: str, hashed_password: str):
        new_user = User(username=username, email=email, hashed_password=Hasher.get_password_hash(hashed_password))
        self.db_session.add(new_user)
        await self.db_session.flush()
        return new_user

    async def check_user(self, email: str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.email==email))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()

    async def check_username(self, username: str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.username==username))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()
    
    async def get_user_by_id(self, id: str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.id==id))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()

    async def get_confirmation_uuid(self, confirmation_uuid: str):
        user_exist = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(str(User.confirmation)==confirmation_uuid))
        #print(user_exist)
        return user_exist.scalar_one_or_none()
```

**auth.py**

```
from jose import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from core.config import Settings
from pydantic import UUID4
import uuid
from passlib.context import CryptContext

settings = Settings()


class Auth:
    password_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

    @classmethod
    def get_password_hash(cls, password: str) -> str:
        return cls.password_context.hash(password)

    @staticmethod
    def get_token(data: dict, expires_delta: int):
        pass
        to_encode = data.copy()
        to_encode.update({
            "exp": datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=expires_delta),
            "iss": settings.PROJECT_NAME
        })
        return jwt.encode(
            to_encode,
            settings.SECRET_KEY,
            algorithm=settings.TOKEN_ALGORITHM
        )

    @staticmethod
    def get_confirmation_token(user_id: UUID4):
        jti = uuid.uuid4()
        claims = {
            "sub": str(user_id),
            "scope": "registration",
            "jti": str(jti)
        }
        return {
            "jti": jti,
            "token": Auth.get_token(
                claims,
                settings.REGISTRATION_TOKEN_LIFETIME
            )
        }
```

**models.py**

```
import uuid
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from db.base_class import Base


class User(Base):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    confirmation = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    jobs = relationship("Job", back_populates="owner")
```

When I try to check Does the user exist? Is the token ID stored in the database? in

```
if not user or await users.get_confirmation_uuid(str(User.confirmation)) != payload['jti']:
```

I get `"detail": "Invalid Token"` and when I `print(User.confirmation)` it gives me `User.id` instead.

After the email sent database log:

```
User.confirmation
1867657b-7cfa-471f-9daa-92ea192abb5a
E-mail has been sent!
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64005 - "POST /registration/?username=usertest&email=tutepoha%40livinginsurance.co.uk&password=usertest123 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-07-16 18:18:37,973 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE "user" SET confirmation=%s WHERE "user".id = %s
2021-07-16 18:18:37,974 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00079s] (UUID('1867657b-7cfa-471f-9daa-92ea192abb5a'), UUID('674ead42-44a3-46b0-9645-689885ace026'))
```

Not sure what the problem is, I've tried de-bugging to my extent but now I've hit a wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different problems in your code now.

In your code :

`if not user or await users.get_confirmation_uuid(str(User.confirmation))!= payload['jti']:`

You check users.get_confirmation_uuid(str(User.confirmation)) As said above, you are comparing a value of your class since you are calling User instead of user. In the second case, you call the instance while in the first, you call the class

And the comparison
`users.get_confirmation_uuid str (user.confirmation))! = Payload ['jti']`
can never be true since your `users.get_confirmation_uuid method` does not return a UID value but a list of User object. So calling it to the `users.get_confirmation` method is actually unnecessary. You just need to do the following:

`if not user or user.confirmation! = payload['jti']:`

But, the problem is more than that. Currently, your method for retrieving a user `users.get_user_by_id(id=payload['sub'])`
returns a list, not a single object. Thus, you must either return a single object or browse the list.

Here is the code I propose to fix all this:

The methods have been changed to return an object and not a list

user_data_access_layer.py

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException, status

from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate
from db_config import SESSION
from auth import Auth

class Users():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    async def save(cls, user_instance):
        try:
            SESSION.add(user_instance)
            SESSION.commit()
        except Exception as error:
            SESSION.rollback()
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_id(cls, id):
        user = await SESSION.query(User).filter(User.id == id).one_or_none()
        return user

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_username(cls, username):
        user = await SESSION.query(User).filter(User.username == username).one_or_none()
        return user

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_email(cls, email):
        user = await SESSION.query(User).filter(User.email == email).one_or_none()
        return user

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_confirmation(cls, confirmation):
        user = await SESSION.query(User).filter(User.confirmation == confirmation).one_or_none()
        return user

    @classmethod
    async def create_user(self, user: UserCreate):
        new_user = User(username=user.username,
                        email=user.email,
                        hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(user.password)
                        )
        cls.save(new_user)
        return new_user
```

routes.py

```py
@router.get("/verify/{token}")
async def verify(token: str, users: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    invalid_token_error = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, detail="Invalid Token")
    
    # TRYING DECODE TOKEN
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, get_settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[
                             get_settings.TOKEN_ALGORITHM])
    except jwt.JWSError:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Token has Expired")
        
    # CHECK IF THE SCOPE IS OK
    if payload['scope'] != 'registration':
        raise invalid_token_error
    
    # TRY TO GET AN USER WITH THE ID FROM TOKEN
    user = await Users.get_user_by_id(id=payload['sub'])
    
    # CHECK IF WE FOUND AN USER AND IF THE UID CONFIRMATION IS THE SAME OF THE TOKEN
    if not user or str(user.confirmation) != str(payload['jti']):
        raise invalid_token_error
    
    # CHECK IF THE USER IS ALREADY ACTIVE
    if user.is_active:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
                            detail="User already Activated")
        
    # IF ALL IT'S OK, WE UPDATE THE CONFIRMATION AND IS_ACTIVE ATTRIBUTE AND CALL THE SAVE METHOD
    user.confirmation = None
    user.is_active = True
    Users.save(user)
    return user
```